# Flowtype declaration in interface file precedence

Tags: flowtype

Trying to Flow type check a node project.  I use a timer and unref it so not to keep the node process running when shutting down.

unref isn't present in timers used in the browser, so to circumvent this I have added a declaration before...

```
declare var setInterval : any;
setInterval(function(){ ...
```

... and type checking succeeds. However if I move this declaration to an interface file (similar to the example [Checking third-party code](http://flowtype.org/docs/third-party.html#_) example) it doesn't appear to be used and I get the following error:

```
call of method unref
Property not found in 
... core.js:70:1,87:1: Number
```

Does the definition in core.js take precedence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this question was posed, the builtin lib files did take precedence over any user lib files and there was no way to override them.

Starting with [Flow v0.19.0](https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases/tag/v0.19.0) (released on Dec. 1st, 2015), you can now override the built in libraries. The the order of precedence from highest to lowest is as follows:

1. Lib files specified from the commandline with `--lib`
2. Lib files specified in the `[libs]` section of the `.flowconfig`
3. The builtin libraries